# Create data with Curly Braces in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, pretty-print, curly-braces

I am trying to create an AST and pretty print it. I am parsing parts of the C language. However, when I have to represent an empty statement, which is

```
{}
```

I am completely stuck, because I am not able to simply create a new Data which contains something like that. Or when it be the following

```
{{}}
```

which would be the equivalent of

```
SScope({})
```

Technically my question is, how I am able to pretty-print in Haskell the Curly braces? So when I receive

```
{}
```

I would like to pretty-print exactly the same, like

```
{}
```

that. And what I would do is something like this:

```
data Stmt = {}
```

like with other data elements, but I am not able to do this. Any advice for that?

Comment: The definition of a statement in your grammar should include both simple statements and compound statements. A compound statement is zero or more statements surrounded by `{` and `}`. So `{}` would simply be a CompoundStatement node with no children.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of a CompoundStatement? Because in practice, I am not sure about what does that exactly mean.

Comment: It's literally `{...}`, with zero or more statements inside. For example, a condition statement is `if(<boolean expression>) <statement>`. `<statement>` can be replaced with an empty statement like `;`, a simple statement like `x = 3;`, or a compound statement, which is defined by the use of `{` to start it and `}` to end it (no terminating `;`). Inside the braces are *zero* or more statements, so you could write `if(1) {}` or `if(1) {x = 3;}` or `if(1) {x = 3; y = 4;}`, etc.

Comment: `{{}}` is a compound statement that contains exactly one statement, another compound statement (that happens to be empty).

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, now I understand it better. Also, I have to edit my question, because I think I made it in a wrong way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the lexical components of your language (the curly braces etc) and the Haskell data types used to represent the syntactic constructs.

The Haskell side should have something like

```
data Stmt = 
    CompoundStmnt [Stmt]
    | ValueStmt Identifier Expression
    |  -- And so on for all the other types of statement you want.
```

Then you define a parser which recognises curly brackets, and a pretty-printer which prints out the values surrounded by curly brackets.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought about using a list when I declare new data.